# Сравнить два DataFrame и вывести одинковые элементы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df1`

```
pas_id
923    [0, 0, 1]
987    [0, 0, 1]
127       [0, 1]
215    [0, 0, 1]
254       [2, 2]
302       [0, 1]
350       [0, 1]
```

`df2`

```
           0
0  [0, 0, 1]
1  [0, 0, 1]
2  [0, 0, 1]
3     [2, 2]
```

Как найии элементы df2 в df1 и вывести их pas_id

***Вывод***

```
       (from df1)    (from df2)

923    [0, 0, 1]     [0,0,1]
987    [0, 0, 1]     [0,0,1]
215    [0, 0, 1]     [0,0,1]
254       [2, 2]     [2,2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
res = df1[df1[0].isin(df2[0])]
```

res:

```
                0
pas_id           
923     [0, 0, 1]
987     [0, 0, 1]
215     [0, 0, 1]
254        [2, 2]
```

Comment: Выпадает ошибка. Это может быть из-за того что столбцы не названы?

Comment: Да, у меня в примере столбец  со списками в первом датафрейме назван 0

Comment: Все, спасибо большое